# concatante list of lists dataframe from pd.read_html DF[0] format

Tags: python, pandas, list, concatenation, scrape

I have a DF[number] = pd.read_html(url.text)

I want to concantante or join the DF lists theres hundreads of e.g. DFs[400] into a single pandas dataframe

the dataframes are in list format so list of lists but python index lists like pandas dataframe

```
     [    Vessel                Built    GT    DWT  Size (m)     Unnamed: 5
 0      x            XIN HUA Bulk Carrier  2012  44543     82269   229 x 32
 1      b  FRANCESCO CORRADO Bulk Carrier  2008  40154     77061   225 x 32
 2      5         NAN XIN 17 Bulk Carrier  2001  40570     75220   225 x 32
 3      p      DIAMOND INDAH Bulk Carrier  2002  43321     77830   229 x 37
 4      NaN         PRIME LILY Bulk Carrier  2012  44485   81507   229 x 32
 5      s           EVGENIA Bulk Carrier  2011  92183    176000   292 x 45



 df[number] = pd.read_html(url.text) 

 for number in range(494):
 df=pd.concat(df[number])
```

methods but that doesn't seem to work

```
  df1=pd.concat(df[1])
  df2=pd.concat(df[2])
  df3=pd.concat(df[3])
  dfx=pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],ignore_index=True)
```

this is not what I want as there is hundreads of [] python list dataframes

I want one pandas dataframe that joins all of the list dataframes into one

just be clear the df[] container of the lists is a dict type while df[1] is list

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```
pd.concat([dfs[i] for i in range(len(dfs))])
```

Comment: typeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'list'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid

Comment: It sounds like you have a list of lists and not a list of dataframes

Comment: yes it is a list of lists but since the list is a python index list similar to a dataframe list of list concat doesn't work to concat them